# Go: delete post with sql

Tags: sql, go

How do I assign each button that appears beside a tweet in the array, the id of the tweet? I have each button printed beside each tweet, so when I click the button, the sql query should delete the relevant tweet beside that button.

I'm using the sql/database stdlib in Go.

html:

```
<form action="/home/tweets" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="tweet" name="twt" placeholder="enter tweet here"></input>
    <button type="Tweet" id="twtbutton">Tweet</button>
    <p id="twt">{{range $i := .Tweetarray}}{{$i}}<br></p>

    <form action="/delete" method="POST" name="xdel">
        <button type="delete" id="xbutton">Delete</button>
    </form>
    {{end}}
</form>
```

Go:

```
func deletehandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    xtweet = r.FormValue("xdel")  //this seems wrong
    DeleteData()
    (//some code to parse template)
}

func DeleteData() {
    db, _ := sql.Open("mysql", "apple@/my_db")
    stmt, _ := db.Prepare("DELETE FROM posts WHERE tweet = ?")
    res, err := stmt.Exec(xtweet)
```

}

What am I doing wrong? Or how can I go about doing this?

Comment: Have you tried debugging with a `log.Println(xtweet)` in your DeleteData function? Further - I'd strongly recommend you don't open a new *connection pool* (which is what sql.Open does) on every request - you should create one pool at start-up, and then share it around or use a global (`var db *sql.DB`). Also make sure you're checking the errors from `db.Open`, `db.Prepare` and `stmt.Exec` - right now they all appear to be ignored.

Comment: okay, I'll check that. My concern is how to extract the value (id) of the post and pass it into each unique button so that when I click it, the button will delete the correct post with that id.

Answer (score 0):

You can associate some kind of value in each individual form submit that indicates the identifier.

A common approach to send that kind of state is to use an **input type="hidden"** form field.  So somewhere in the emitted HTML template, perhaps something like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="tweetId" value="{{$i}}">
```

or whatever value you need there to uniquely identify the tweet.